# Pyfakefs not supporting os.renames?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-module, python-os, pyfakefs

Here's a simple piece of code I wanted to test:

```
import os

def move_all(firstPath, secondPath):
  for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(firstPath)):
    print('moving '+str(count) + '   '+filename)
    os.rename((firstPath+'\\'+filename),(secondPath+'\\'+filename))

def test_fakefs(fs):
  fakeDirectory = '\\fakeroot\\fakefolder'
  fakeFile1 = 'fake_file.txt'
  fakeFile2 = 'fake_file_2.txt'

  fs.create_dir(fakeDirectory)
  fs.create_file(fakeDirectory+"\\"+fakeFile1)
  fs.create_file(fakeDirectory+'\\'+fakeFile2)
  fs.create_dir(fakeDirectory+'2')

  move_all(fakeDirectory,(fakeDirectory+'2'))
  assert os.path.exists(fakeDirectory+'2\\fake_file.txt')
```

When running this using *pytest*, everything seems to work. However, if I switch 6th line to *renames*:

```
os.renames((firstPath+'\\'+filename),(secondPath+'\\'+filename))
```

I get

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\fakeroot\fakefolder\fake_file.txt' -> '\fakeroot\fakefolder2\fake_file.txt'

Am I doing something wrong or does **pyfakefs** not support this os method? The very same function works as intended on a real file system.

Comment: I can reproduce this and created a [respective issue](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs/issues/714). I will see if I can fix this over the weekend.

Comment: Update: shall be fixed in latest release.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked version 5.0.0 and everything seems to work as expected.